# Finding the chi-squared distribution of a squared difference of two independent normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Given two independent random variables $X\sim N(0, \sigma^2), Y\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, what is the distribution of a variable $Q = (X-Y)^2/4$ ? What would be the expected value and variance of $Q$?

Comment: The distribution of $Q$ depends on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, not just their marginal distributions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing notation, hopefully my edit makes things more clear? $Q$ is proportional to the difference of two independent instances of the same distribution, not two separate distributions

Comment: That's surely not what you intended at all. $X - X$ is identically zero, and so $P(Q=0)=1$. I wasn't asking you to change *notation*. I was asking you to talk about the joint distribution of the two underlying variables in your question. Perhaps you intended that they be independent?

Comment: Ah ok sorry, maybe now it's cleared up? I did intend them to be independent

Comment: @Galaxy Usually, a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ is written $N(0, \sigma^2)$. If you write $N(0,\sigma)$, do you really mean that the variance is $\sigma$ and not $\sigma^2$, i.e. you use the symbol $\sigma$, that is usually used for the standard deviation, as the symbol for the variance?

Answer (score 1):

Below, I presume that you actually want X and Y to have variance $\sigma^2$, and not $\sigma$.

Since $N(0, \sigma^2)$ is symmetric over zero, the random variable $Y$ is equal to the random variable $-Y$. Thus $X-Y$ is just the sum of two independent normal distributions $N(0, \sigma^2)$. Using the [general formula for the sum of two independent normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables) $A\sim N(\mu_A, \sigma_A^2), B\sim N(\mu_B, \sigma_B^2)$:
$$
A+B \sim N(\mu_A + \mu_B, \; \sigma^2_A + \sigma_B^2)
$$

we get for $X-Y$:
$$
\begin{align}
X-Y &\sim N(0, 2\sigma^2),\\
\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} &\sim N(0, 1).
\end{align}
$$
Next, the square of a $N(0, 1)$ variable has a [$\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) of degree one, i.e. $\left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2\sigma}\right)^2$ is $\chi^2_1$-distributed. Furthermore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(X-Y)^2}{4} &= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2 \sigma (X-Y)}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}\right)^2\\
    &= \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}\right)^2.\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, it is a scaled $\chi^2_1$-distribution, and the scaling factor is $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$. Now, the $\chi^2_1$ distribution has mean equal to one, and variance equal to two. Since the expectation is linear, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{(X-Y)^2}{4}\right] &= \frac{\sigma^2}{2}E\left[\left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}\right)^2\right]\\
    &=\frac{\sigma^2}{2}.
\end{align}
$$
The variance is quadratic, thus
$$
\begin{align}
Var\left[\frac{(X-Y)^2}{4}\right] &= \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)^2 Var\left[\left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt 2 \sigma}\right)^2\right]\\
    &=\frac{\sigma^4}{4}\cdot 2\\
    &= \frac{\sigma^4}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! If you have the time, would you mind explaining why $Q$ only has one degree of freedom? My intuition tells me there should be either two since $Q$ is a function of two independent variables $X$ and $Y$, or three since if you multiply out the squared sum you would get $Q=(X^2+Y^2-2XY)/4$ which is a sum of three chi-squared distributions

Comment: @Galaxy $Z = (X-Y)/(\sqrt 2\sigma)$ is a single $N(0,1)$ random variable, so its square is $\chi^2_1$, i.e. of degree 1 (by definition, the degree is the number of random variables you sum the squares of). Note, that your $Q$ is a square of a sum, not a sum of squares. And if you multiply $Q$ out, this doesn't give a sum of squares of independent random variables.